# How do I dynamically add a badge to the button?

Tags: ios, swift, xlpagertabstrip

I want to add a badge to the tabs when I receive a new update from DB. Is there a method that I can call to update the `IndicatorInfo`?

Unable to figure out please help.

Comment: tabbarcontroller's tab ?

Comment: No a paging menu viewcontroller pod. https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip

Comment: [https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip/issues/302](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip/issues/302)

Comment: Thanks. I tried, but it either takes a title or an image. I have a title, plus add a badge dynamically.

Comment: Are you trying to set badge on `UITabBarController`'s tab?

Comment: No XLPagerTabStrip

Answer (score 1):

I had to play around with the XIB file, and set constraints and handle cases manually.

### Steps Performed

1. Add constraints to the `UIImageView` in the `ButtonCell.xib` file to align itself beside the `UILabel`. (I added them on a `UIView` to ensure the views are centred.)
2. Changed to following code in `ButtonBaragerTabStripViewController`

   ```
   buttonBarItemSpec = .nibFile(nibName: "ButtonCell", bundle: Bundle(for: ButtonBarViewCell.self), width: { [weak self] (childItemInfo) -> CGFloat in
               let label = UILabel()
               label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
               label.font = self?.settings.style.buttonBarItemFont
               label.text = childItemInfo.title
               let labelSize = label.intrinsicContentSize
           return labelSize.width + (childItemInfo.image != nil ? 35.0 : 0.0) + (self?.settings.style.buttonBarItemLeftRightMargin ?? 8) * 2
       })
   ```
3. Added constraints `@IBOutlet` and setting it's `constant` value to `0.0` when image isn't supposed to be there.